# Can someone explain this line of Scala code to me?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Scala syntax has been driving me nuts. Below is a line of Scala from a Spark driver program. I get most of it except the very end.

```
val ratings = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
```

The (2) just floating out there doesn't make sense. I understand intellectually that it's the third item in the RDD, but why is there not a dot or something connecting it to the rest of the statement?

Comment: Parentheses are Scala's syntax for a function call. It's actually no different from most other languages. E.g. ECMAScript and Python are the same way.

Comment: I've been writing code for 15 years in various languages. I didn't know .split() was an array which would have helped but more importantly, no other language I've worked with chains things together the way Scala does. Sometimes I see this in C# inside of SSIS but I just figured that was a quirk of the tool not C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Scala's syntax for accessing an `Array` element.

```
x.toString().split("\t")
```

The above returns an `Array`. Adding the `(2)` returns the third element in that array. This is syntactic sugar for calling `.apply(2)` on the array, which gives you the element at the supplied index.

An example:

```
val numbers = Array("beaver", "aardvark", "warthog")
numbers(0) // "beaver"; same as numbers.apply(0)
numbers(1) // "aardvark"
numbers(2) // "warthog"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the string x is split into an array and this is the syntax to access the array element

Answer (score 0):

In my observation

```
val fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");

fruits.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(0))
Array[String] = Array(Apple, Banana, Orange)

fruits.map(x => x.toString().split("\t"))    
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(Apple), Array(Banana), Array(Orange))

fruits.map(x => x.toString())
Array[String] = Array(Apple, Banana, Orange)
```